# SharePoint 2013 apps do not show up

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment and I have the publishing features enabled.  When I try to add Apps, only 3 show up:  Document Library, Custom Lists, & Tasks.  If I turn off Publishing, then a whole plethora of apps re-appear.

We have gone through all the steps of setting up an app domain and creating an app catalog.  On the app catalog site, I create a new app from the Announcements app called News & Announcements, and I want to add this to my main site.  No matter what I do, I cannot get it to show up in my site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a custom app 'News & Annoucements' in app catalog site? If yes, did you install it within 'Apps for SharePoint'? Check if the 'Enabled' property is checked within the properties for that custom app.

Comment: I didn't create it in Visual Studio if that's what you're asking.  On the app catalog site, under Site Contents I clicked on "Add an app" then under "Apps you can add" I clicked Announcements, gave it a name of "News & Announcements" and clicked "Create".  It shows up fine in the App catalog site, but doesn't show up on any of my site collections.

I can't find anywhere to set the properties like you suggested.

Comment: The 'News & Annoucements' app you created under App catalog is nothing but a list that will be available only to App catalog site collection. It's same as creating a list in any site or site collection. If your intention is to create an App that will be available throughout your tenant you need to create .app files (custom app) and install it within App catalog.

Comment: That's cool, I understand that. But how come virtually no apps (except the 3 mentioned above) show up on my main site.  If I turn Publishing features back on, they will show up, but I need Publishing, and need these apps.  HELP!!

Comment: Try going to Site Collection features (_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site) and see what all features are turned on, some of the apps require particular feature to be turned on. Check for 'SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features', 'Video and Rich Media', 'SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features'  and see if they are on, If not, turn them on. 
Which template did you select when you first created your site collection? I'm guessing you might have used blank template. Also, try creating a new site collection with different template & see if problem still exist.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  All of the relevant features are turned on, however after some experimentation, it seems that the issue is related to the custom theme I am running on the site.  

I created a subsite and they show up. I turn on Publishing, causing it to inherit its theme and the apps disappear.  If I re-enable one of the OOTB themes, the apps re-appear.  

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your theme XML?
Use theme builder from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182

Comment: Sure, all i've done is create an .spcolor file in the Sharepoint color designer.  Here is XML from that

http://pastebin.com/3JKdB8FD

Answer (score 5):

I believe I have solved my problem.  After some experimentation, I think there was a flaw in my master page.  I had done some customization to seattle.html and I must have done something to bomb out the section that handles the additional apps.

I created a new site collection and copied the seattle.html from the new to the existing, then applied my theme and it seems to be working fine now.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: For me, it was because I had commented out `<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">` Code. Thank you! Placed it back in, made a calendar and commented it back in! :)

Answer (score 4):

The specific cause for 'Apps you can add' not showing up is one of maybe 4 ContentPlaceHolders either missing from the master page or set to Visible="False".

- DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar
- PlaceHolderLeftNavBar
- DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea
- PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea

In my case I had to set PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea to Visible="True".

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" Visible="True" runat="server" />
```

Source: http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html

Comment: This section is for answers only, when you have gained some more rep you will be able to post comments

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. It's a bug in Microsofts JavaScript code. The app icons on the "Add an app" page are loaded via AJAX and the code is hard-coded to set the text of the span with id 'ms-pageTitleCurrentNode' in the PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea (and in the QuickLaunch, too). So if you remove either the Title or QuickLaunch area via masterpage modification you will end up without the app list.

As a workaround you might try to add the span anywhere on the page. Since the text "Your apps" will be set on it you might also want to hide the span via CSS if you don't want to see this text appear on your page.

In case of the removed QuickLaunch I don't know of any quick fix, so you better don't remove it in the masterpage and set its visibility via CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

I re-instated the following lines into my SharePoint Online master page and it restored the additional apps at the cost of having extra controls on the page:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Very grateful to the contributors on this post for guidance on this.